# Convert Excel math to JavaScript - trouble with ABS(Excel) to Modulus(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, excel

I have been converting an Excel spreadsheet to a JavaScript form all day.

It has gone pretty well. I have most of them working just fine.

I have been thrown by this one though:

**EXCEL FORMULA:**

```
G20*((G33-0.015)^(G17-G16))*((1-G33^(ABS(G17-G16)))/(1-G33))))
```

**My JavaScript conversion:**

```
var calc = tax_per_year*(Math.pow((inflation - 0.015), (career_start-age)))*((1 - Math.pow(inflation, (%(career_start - age)))/(1 - inflation)));
```

It seems that JavaScript does not like the placement of the converted **Excel "ABS"** converted to **JavaScript "%" Modulus**

**Am I using this modulus correctly here?**
I have tried a variety of placements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using modulo in this scenario is wrong and makes no sense in this case. Modulo delivers you the rest of a division.
Just use the javascript abs function.

```
Math.abs(<your_value>);
```

Or have a look at the W3C Reference.
[Math.abs (W3C Reference)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp)